# I cant Seem to get whats wrong with my code, i cant get the total value

Tags: php

I cant get the total value, it displays 0. can anybody help me with this part of my code.

```
while($test = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
  $customer_id= $test['customer_id'];

  $total = ($test['price']*$test['qty']);

  echo "<tr>"; 
  echo "<td>". $test['name']. "</td>";
  echo "<td>". $test['email']. "</td>";
  echo "<td>". $test['p_num']. "</td>";
  echo "<td>". $test['address']. "</td>";
  echo "<td>". $test['message']. "</td>";
  echo "<td>". $test['ord']. "</td>";
  echo "<td>". $test['price']. "</td>";
  echo "<td>". $test['qty']. "</td>";
  echo "<td>". $total. "</td>";
  echo "<td>". $test['ord_date']. "</td>";
```

Comment: what the price and qty values in this case

Comment: can you please share to us the sample output of your code? so that we can base our answers related on your result..

Answer (score 1):

Check price and quantity value for each loop if price or qty is 0 it will return 0 ;

You need to sum all iterated value

```
$total += ($test['price']*$test['qty']);
```

Comment: I think `$total` is not intended to be summed on all the loops.. since for every loop, `$total` is displayed..